# LinkedIn premium job publication API v.2: cryptic error message: INVALID_DATA detected while constructingPremiumJobIngestionContext

Tags: linkedin-api

Context: earlier this year our company implemented the LinkedIn premium job publication API v.2 to publish jobs to LinkedIn for our customers.

For the last few months this has proved to work reliably. But now it turns out not to work for 1 of our customers.

On the first step in the API publication process: this is the reply we get.

```
{"errorMessage":"The job listing failed due to an internal server
error:INVALID_DATA detected while
constructingPremiumJobIngestionContext","id":"urn:li:simpleJobPostingTask:ea15c40a-58ad-4360-8d5f-87c4ecea0540","status":"FAILED"}},"errors":{}}
```

Our first thought was that this would be because of customer credentials. But we've gone through 3 rounds of verifying those with the customer now.

Most of the previous error-messages from the API we've been able to figure out, but this one is positively cryptic.

Are there any known causes for the `INVALID_DATA detected while constructingPremiumJobIngestionContext` error message?

Answer (score 0):

When setting up a job posting partner for the jobs API, as in the following link:
https://www.linkedin.com/help/recruiter/answer/50383/authorizing-a-job-posting-partner-api?lang=en

Clients need to choose a default poster.

The Error you are seeing is often caused by the default poster no longer having access to the Dashboard/contract used for the jobs API. 
Your client will need to check and adjust the default poster on their end.